# What is the path of oratab on solaris?

Tags: oracle, solaris

What is the path of oratab on solaris?

This is actually a question I google a lot and switching from environment to another, I tend to mix them up and forget.

Today I googled it again and I wanted it in a place where I usually have all the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file is:

```
/var/opt/oracle/oratab
```